# How to update a store with a form in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, extjs-stores

I have store and I add a new record with this code. First it adds the new record and then it synchronizes to the back-end.

```
Ext.getStore('ilhan').add(Ext.getCmp('contacForm').getValues());
Ext.getStore('ilhan').sync({
    success: function(){
        Ext.getStore('ilhan').load();
        Ext.getCmp('customerWindow').close();
    }
});
```

I can also delete a record with this code below.

```
Ext.getStore('ilhan').remove(Ext.getCmp('theGrid').getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0]);
Ext.getStore('ilhan').sync({
    success: function(){
        Ext.getStore('ilhan').load();
    }
});
```

But I don't know how to update a record. I can only fill up the form with the data from the row of the grid.

```
Ext.getCmp('contacEditForm').getForm().setValues(Ext.getCmp('theGrid').getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].data);
```

So, I have `add` and `remove` methods for store but I don't have any `update` method? How I'm supposed to update the store?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using [Model](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.Model).

```
Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'email'],

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url : '/users'
    }
});
```

Create:

```
var user = Ext.create('User', {name: 'Ed Spencer', email: 'ed@sencha.com'});

user.save(); //POST /users
```

Load:

```
//Uses the configured RestProxy to make a GET request to /users/123
User.load(123, {
    success: function(user) {
        console.log(user.getId()); //logs 123
    }
});
```

Update:

```
//the user Model we loaded in the last snippet:
user.set('name', 'Edward Spencer');

//tells the Proxy to save the Model. In this case it will perform a PUT request to /users/123 as this Model already has an id
user.save({
    success: function() {
        console.log('The User was updated');
    }
});
```

Delete:

```
//tells the Proxy to destroy the Model. Performs a DELETE request to /users/123
user.erase({
    success: function() {
        console.log('The User was destroyed!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To update.

```
var form = Ext.getCmp('contacForm'),
    record = form.getRecord(),
    values = form.getValues(),
    store = Ext.getStore('ilhan');
record.set(values);
store.sync({
    success:function() {
        store.load()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at your record.  See if the 'dirty' property is true.  That's what the proxies use to determine if a record is a post or a put.